# Using 2 methods to display markers and polylines on a Google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am trying to combine two separate methods to display both markers and polylines on one map. Is it possible? and if so how would I do this. Or conversely how would I add polylines to my markers sample.

From http://you.arenot.me/2010/06/29/google-maps-api-v3-0-multiple-markers-multiple-infowindows/

Without my actual code I appreciate this is a probably a wasted post.. but I am having trouble adding my code.. 
Perhaps that should have been my first question..

Comment: Do you want to combine the markers on your map with the polylines. Can you elaborate?

Comment: No, I want to add polylines to the map. Colin, the guy who provided the code for my markers seems to have used a unique and sweet process but... I can not, try as I will add a polyline to it

Answer (score 0):

This script will add markers and draw a polyline between them:

```
<script>

  var poly;
  var map;

  function initialize() {
    var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.879535, -87.624333);
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 7,
      center: chicago,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);

    var polyOptions = {
      strokeColor: '#000000',
      strokeOpacity: 1.0,
      strokeWeight: 3
    }
    poly = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOptions);
    poly.setMap(map);

    // Add a listener for the click event
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', addLatLng);
  }

  /**
   * Handles click events on a map, and adds a new point to the Polyline.
   * @param {MouseEvent} mouseEvent
   */
  function addLatLng(event) {

    var path = poly.getPath();

    // Because path is an MVCArray, we can simply append a new coordinate
    // and it will automatically appear
    path.push(event.latLng);

    // Add a new marker at the new plotted point on the polyline.
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: event.latLng,
      title: '#' + path.getLength(),
      map: map
    });
  }

</script>
```

Excellent Documentation available here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-complex

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately this method does not seem compatible with the method I am using for my markers. Colin.. the guy who made the code found at http://you.arenot.me/2010/06/29/google-maps-api-v3-0-multiple-markers-multiple-infowindows/ evidently used some special tricks to make a very slick map with markers.. but adding any standard features seems impossible.

Comment: Got it to work.. and was going to show the code I ended up inserting.. but it seems I can not do that. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly possible to display markers and polylines on the same map:

- [Here](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GenericMapBrowser.asp?filename=SteveFossett.xml) is an example that displays both markers and independent polylines.
- [Here](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?filename=mtrmtrip.xml) is an example that uses the third party geoxml3 KML parser to create them from a KML file (or using KmlLayer).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I may have to rethink my whole approach and use a more standard method for my markers and polylines